# Create multiple documents with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following array:

```
@unregistered_users = ['my@email.com', 'your@email.com', ...]
```

Now, I want to create a document for each array element:

```
@unregistered_users.each do |email_address|
  Model.create(email: email_address, user: self.user, detail: self)
end
```

But it only creates a single document (the first element of the array). The other array elements are simply not created. Why?

We're using Ruby 1.9.3-p385, Rails 3.2.12, MongoID 3.0.0 and MongoDB 2.2.3

### Update #1

So, we had a custom `_id` field with a custom random token using `SecureRandom.hex(64).to_i(16).to_s(36)[0..127]`.

After I removed it worked normally, but with regular mongo ID's (which is not what we want).

### Update #2

This is how the token are being generated:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  ...
  field :_id, default: SecureRandom.hex(64).to_i(16).to_s(36)[0..127]
  ...

  index( { _id: 1 }, { unique: true } )
end
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Anything of interest in the logs? Do you have `uniqueness` validations that could make the iteration fail?

Comment: Maybe the content of the array isn't what you expect, have you tried doing for example `@unregistered_users.each {|u| puts u}`.

Comment: @jesper, no errors. I do have a `uniqueness` on the `Model` class. Since is a custom mongo ID: `index( { _id: 1 }, { unique: true } )`/ Actually I have logged the @unregistered_users and has the expected content.

Comment: Have you tried running the same code in `rails console`?

Comment: @jesper, Yep, and got the same results. It only creates the first element.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm stumped :/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to check what are the errors on the mongoid model:

```
@unregistered_users.each do |email_address|
  model = Model.create(email: email_address, user: self.user, detail: self)
  puts model.errors.inspect unless model.persisted?
end
```

or use `create!` to raise an exception and see what's happening

Comment: Still having the same results: creates only one document.

Comment: But, don't you have any message ?

Comment: @betacar can you post your mongoid.yml, and the Model code? Also could you try something like this: `Model.with(safe: true).create(<your params>)`

Comment: @betacar I just read your **Update #1**, please share your `Model` code, how are you setting the custom `_id`?

Comment: Edgar, done. I had to strip out other non-related fields and relations.